# How to highlight and made clickable only one specific part of the whole object?

Tags: three.js

I have an object that dynamically changes color depending on some information from a server, and I want to have possibility to click on a specific colored part of the object. Please give me any tips and suggestions how can I implement this.

Comment: You could use raycasting : https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know this tool, don't think about using it this way, but I will take a closer look at this.